# How to remove Google Safe Browsing?

Tags: internet, google

Google has infiltrated my Ubuntu 16.04 system with a program called "Google Safe Browsing"  It is a pain in the neck, restricting access to various websites.  How can I get rid of it?  I am not a programmer, so go slow.  Thanks.

I use Firefox as my browser.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu @geode56! How did you install the software, and which browser are you using?

Comment: *Google has infiltrated my system* No, it didn't. You authorized it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Ubuntu or an Ubuntu application but for a Google Software and more specifically, Google Chrome.

Comment: @NickTux It's on-topic to ask about applications that run on Ubuntu like Chrome. ["Questions that you may ask: Running third-party applications on Ubuntu."](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I think you have a point here. Although this is a question about a feature of Google Chrome, that is a cross-platform software, it could be fit here under the scope that is running on Ubuntu. But again, this is not a problem bonded with Ubuntu. In either case, I'm retracting my vote.

Comment: I am running Firefox,  I have never knowingly "authorized" the program.  It restricts my access to sites that are determined by Google to be risky or inappropriate.  I simply want control of my system.

Answer (score 5):

Google Chrome:

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.
3. Click **Tools**.
4. Choose *Extensions*.
5. Find "*Safe Browsing*".
6. Click the trash can icon to remove it.

Mozilla Firefox:

1. Open Firefox.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
3. Choose "*Safe Browsing*".
4. Click Disable or Remove button.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Chrome.

These are steps you can follow to disable the warnings(since you're talking of "pain in the ass!") about dangerous & deceptive sites:

- On your computer, open Chrome.
- At the top right, click 'More' > 'Settings'.
- At the bottom, click 'Advanced'.
- Under 'Privacy and security', toggle the "button" next to "Protects you and your device from dangerous sites" as shown in the image attached.

[image: safe browsing]

You could have a look at this [Help Center article](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020) if deemed necessary for more. It would help you manage warnings about unsafe sites.

Hope this helps you!